# Changes to razor view not showing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor

I have made some changes to a view in my ASP.NET MVC3 application, but the changes I have made are not showing up when I test/debug the site within the browser. The changes I am making are simple text amendments to the markup.

I am using the Visual Studio development server for testing the application.

The odd thing is, I have tried publishing these changes to IIS and the changes I have made to the view are working when I test the application using the IIS server.

It is only when testing in the Visual Studio environment that this seems to happen.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A common problem i've run into is when you are not using IE and you close the debug session, but not your browser.

This means that the "IIS/development server" is still running in your system tray, but it is running on the old compiled code, if you hit ctrl + shift + b, you build your entire solution and re-publish your code to your development server. this allows you to hit refresh (F5) in your browser and the changes you've made to the razor view should now be reflected in your browser.

Comment: I had tried your suggestion but the view was still not displaying the correct markup.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IE? Maybe deleting the cache or using another browser should work? I've had a lot of problems with that :D

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use [IIS Express](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview). For some reason, the VS development server doesn't recognise changes to code behind - nothing to do with caching on the browser.
However the location of the source code as suggested in other answers is important - it works for me using the `c:\windows` folder or `c:\users\DefaultAppPool` - apparently it has something to do with security to ensure.

Only applications running under the 'DefaultAppPool' identity are permitted under IIS. So, for anyone using a VM and mapping the host OS code folder you won't be able to rectify this unless you copy to a local folder in the `c:\users\DefaultAppPool` folder.

You may also now have difficulties accessing the SQL server database established for the Membership Provider under ASP.NET. For more details on how to fix that, I've [posted](http://www.appsolo.com/index.php/2012/09/14/localhost-not-refreshing-to-reflect-code-changes/) on my blog.